# how to use jmeter OS process sampler

Tags: jmeter

I am very new to jmeter. I am trying to use OS Process Sampler to run python scripts of mine. [image]

but keep getting the error.

[image]

Is my configuration wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fail to see where you provide the path to your [Python script](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-run-a-python-script/) (the file with .py extension)

Here is my `hello.py` script:

```
import sys

if len(sys.argv) >= 2:
    name = sys.argv[1]
else:
    name = 'World'
print('Hello', name)
```

which lives under `/tmp` folder

And I can invoke it with the parameter like:

[image]

[image]

So the first argument should be the path to your Python script and then put each and every argument on the new line like:

- `-s`
- `SK2850`
- `-u`
- `xxxxx`
- etc.

More information: [How to Run External Commands and Programs Locally and Remotely from JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter)

Comment: Dmitri thanks so much for your wonderful help. It is working now.